# UPDATE column using a window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3

I have a table named `cat` with the three following columns of interest:

`ID`, `SOURCE`, `TIME`

`ID` and `TIME` values are unique (i.e. no duplicates) but several rows have the same `SOURCE` value

I would like to update each value of the `SOURCE` column, setting it to the `ID` value of the first input row in each group of rows having the same `SOURCE` value and ordered in `TIME` ascending.

In a `SELECT` statement, I would use:

```
SELECT
first_value(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY SOURCE ORDER BY TIME ASC) AS SOURCE
FROM cat;
```

So I tried this for the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE cat
SET SOURCE = first_value(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY SOURCE ORDER BY TIME ASC);
```

Which returns the following error:
`ERROR:  window functions are not allowed in UPDATE`

Could someone help me to find a fast way of doing this given that `cat` has ~800 000 rows and 322 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a common table expression to compute the new value, and then apply the new value to the original table, like:

```
with cte as (
    select      
        id, 
        time,
        first_value(id) over (partition by source order by time asc) as source
    from cat
)
update cat set cat.source = cte.source
from cte
where cte.id = cat.id and cte.time = cat.time
```

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly and it was rather fast (~8 min) given the size of my table. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase this using *aggregation* (in essence) rather than a window function:

```
UPDATE cat c
    SET SOURCE = cc.ID
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (SOURCE) c.*
          FROM cat
          ORDER BY SOURCE, TIME
         ) cc
    WHERE cc.SOURCE = c.SOURCE;
```

This is safer because it does not make any assumptions in the data about 1-1 matches on the rows -- your question does not specify any primary key on the table.  It might also have better performance with an index on `(SOURCE, TIME)`; however, that might depend on the distribution of values in the data.

The above does not handle `NULL` values for `SOURCE`, but that is easily handled:

```
    WHERE cc.SOURCE IS NOT DISTINCT FROM c.SOURCE;
```